# Null space and vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Must a $5\times 5$ matrix contain a $5$-dimensional vector space even if it contains a free column, or it has a $1$-dimensional null-space?

Comment: How can a matrix contain a vector space?

Comment: @Bernard In the sense of row/column spaces (for this question the axis choice is irrelevant; only the _rank_ matters).

Comment: I guess you're asking if the *rank* of every $5\times 5$ matrix must be $5$. And, of course, not.

Comment: But is vector space to sum of null space and column space ? or am I wrong ?